# how to access the object function with var keyword in javascript?

Tags: javascript

** Is there any way to call this without using bind concept,, because i want to store the function inside the scope only with var keyword, then i want to call it from outside ?? **

```
var car = { 
    registrationNumber: "GA12345",
    brand: "Toyota",

    var displayDetails: function(){
        console.log(this.registrationNumber + " " + this.brand);
    }
}

car.displayDetails();
```

*Error* : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Remove the var in the object.  That's not valid syntax, as it is telling you.

Comment: You say you don't want to remove it.  Do you want to not remove it more, or want it to work more?  Because you can't have both.

Comment: _Why_ don't you want to remove the var?

Comment: Unless you're creating your own language, you have to remove the var.

Comment: @NathanChampion Actually previously i had call the function as car.displayDetails() without using var in It It's Work fine That's how we call the function inside object, after that  i tries to store it in variable i called the function it's not working as accepted,, so i know the concept of bind that first we have to bind with this keyword,, but i want to know is there any concept where i store the function in variable and call it from outside the scope???

Comment: @Taplar I don't want to use bind function to call the this keyword , Is there any way to call this without bind function

Comment: @Mário I don't want to create my won language sorry for  not asking the question in right way i am new to this,, but my question is without using bind function is there any way to access the function inside the object which is store in variable. i apologize for my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your [syntax for an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) is incorrect, here is the correction:

```js
var car = { 
    registrationNumber: "GA12345",
    brand: "Toyota",

    displayDetails: function(){
        console.log(this.registrationNumber + " " + this.brand);
    }
}

var myCarDetails = car.displayDetails.bind(car); 
myCarDetails();
```